# Should I use bind or close an alias in for 'this'?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I can make a variable or do bind. What is the best solution?

```
var object = {
    log: function (s) {
        console.log(s);
    },
    run: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                self.log('test');
            }, 1000
        );
    }
};
object.run();
```

or:

```
var object = {
    log: function (s) {
        console.log(s);
    },
    run: function () {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                this.log('test');
            }.bind(this), 1000
        );
    }
};
object.run();
```

Update:
There are many way ways to decide upon this. The aspects of compatibility, performance and readability are the most important.

The Function.prototype.bind function is quite new, so check the compatibility tables before use.

About performance it is best to use self. When calling the function multiple times bind may be better, but that is out of the scope of this question.

I like bind better for readability.

Comment: What do you mean by *best*? Both solutions work and will give the same result.

Comment: Isn't there anything that could make one better than the other?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by *better*? Readability? Performance?

Comment: What could be a reason to prefer one to the other? And how do all those reasons add up?

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind` [is not compatible through all browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind). So it depends on what you care.

Comment: Are you asking which one has the best performance? Which one is more readable?

Comment: Anything, as I as a programmer come in lots of different environments. I already have: compatibility, performance, readability

Comment: I prefer method one as it covers all 3 issues you mentioned. [Here's a compatibility fix for `.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) if you will. But in the end it all boils down on personal preference and how it fits into your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the source for the `Function.prototype.bind` [shim at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), you will note that it forms a closure over several variables in the function that it returns.

Given that, you might as well (IMHO) take advantage of the language features and just close over the variable(s) you need yourself.  You'll be avoiding a function call.

Using `.bind` *is* very useful when you don't control the source of the function that you're calling and you need to set `this`, or if you want to supply additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a "Best solution" here; both options work. I personally like the var self=this; because the code is less verbose and normally fits the purpose.

However as stated by Dan Lee: Function.prototype.bind [is not compatible through all browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind).

Maybe you could use either [underscore bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) 
or [jQuery proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).